# Protege error message Load Error OntologyID using

Tags: ontology, protege

I have problem with Protege
I am trying to replace the URI with http://www.pizza.com/ontologies/pizza.owl
but this does not work I got message
Load Error OntologyID
[image]

The way I do it first I open the protege then from the File I click New
Then again from the file I click Open From URL I try to add http://www.pizza.com/ontologies/pizza.owl

but I got the error

am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The URL you pasted cannot be resolved. `Open from URL` tries to download the ontology file located by that URL, and that process is not working.

Are you trying to load an existing ontology, or to create an ontology named `http://www.pizza.com/ontologies/pizza.owl`? If the second, you can just paste the URL in the ontology IRI textbox in the Protege window, without `Open from URL`.

If instead you're trying to open a remote ontology, you must use a resolvable URL.